# Finding length of list without using the 'len' function in python

Tags: list, jython

In my High school assignment part of it is to make a function that will find the average number in a list of floating points. We can't use len and such so something like `sum(numList)/float(len(numList))` isn't an option for me. I've spent an hour researching and racking my brain for a way to find the list length without using the `len` function, and I've got nothing so I was hoping to be either shown how to do it or to be pointed in the right direction. Help me stack overflow, your my only hope. :)

Comment: Start with a counter and a total of 0, then increment them by 1 and the value respectively... after you've looped the list, do the final calc?

Comment: You could find the length of the list by calling `numList.__len__` >:)

Comment: @OozeMeister did you even read the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop to add up the values from the list, and count them at the same time:

```
def average(numList):
    total = 0
    count = 0
    for num in numList:
        total += num
        count += 1

    return total / count
```

If you might be passed an empty list, you might want to check for that first and either return a predetermined value (e.g. `0`), or raise a more helpful exception than the `ZeroDivisionError` you'll get if you don't do any checking.

If you're using Python 2 and the list might be all integers, you should either put `from __future__ import division` at the top of the file, or convert one of `total` or `count` to a `float` before doing the division (initializing one of them to `0.0` would also work).

Comment: Thankyou so much, i just finished up a 10 hours shift after like no sleep and today is pretty much the only time i have to work on this before it's due. Thankyou so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Might as well show how to do it with a `while` loop since it's another opportunity to learn.

Normally, you won't need counter variable(s) inside of a `for` loop. However, there are certain cases where it's helpful to keep a count as well as retrieve the item from the list and this is where [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) comes in handy.

Basically, the below solution is what @Blckknght's solution is doing internally.

```
def average(items):
    """
        Takes in a list of numbers and finds the average.
    """
    if not items:
        return 0
    # iter() creates an iterator.
    # an iterator has gives you the .next()
    # method which will return the next item
    # in the sequence of items.
    it = iter(items)
    count = 0
    total = 0
    while True:
        try:
            # when there are no more
            # items in the list
            total += next(it)
        # a stop iteration is raised
        except StopIteration:
            # this gives us an opportunity
            # to break out of the infinite loop
            break
        # since the StopIteration will be raised
        # before a value is returned, we don't want
        # to increment the counter until after
        # a valid value is retrieved
        count += 1
    # perform the normal average calculation
    return total / float(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def length_of_list(my_list):
      if not my_list:
           return 0
      return 1+length_of_list(my_list[1:])
```